# How to indent subsections in text without affecting references?

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, cleveref

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1mm}{}{}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}\label{1-0-0}
\section{one}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{Title}\label{1-1-1}
for this text. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 


References:

\Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}

\Cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}

\Cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

There are two issues:

1. The reference to subsection **1. Title** is called `Section` instead of `Subsection`.
2. The number in the reference is the number that I want to show in the text, `1.`, but in the reference I want the full number, `1.1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not redefine `\thesubsection` if the appearance should only be changed in the subsection header. Use `\titleformat` instead:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
```

To change the name reference name of the subsections printed by `\Cref` use:

```
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}%
\Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}\label{1-0-0}
\section{one}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{Title}\label{1-1-1}
for this text. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 

References:

\Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}

\Cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}

\Cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: After all these years, still having to bother others for something I ought to be able to figure out by myself. Sigh. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, my MWE was too small as it did not include tables of contents created with titletoc.  Modifying this question seemed too awkward at this point and so I have asked a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384295/formatting-cref-affects-tables-of-contents