# Formatting \Cref affects Tables of Contents

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, cleveref, titletoc

I recently got help for formatting *subsections* numbers without changing reference numbers. ([How to indent subsections in text without affecting references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384058/how-to-indent-subsections-in-text-without-affecting-references/384072#384072)) which did just what I had asked.

Unfortunately, my working example included neither a `book table of contents` nor a `chapter table of content` and I just found out that both the `book toc` and the `chapter toc` list the *subsections* which I don't want.

Also, there are weird things: the `chapter 1 toc` starts with "chapter.1" and while the `chapter 2 toc` should be empty it is an unformatted copy of the `chapter 1 toc` (along with the  "chapter.1" up front.)

None of which, of course, may have anything to do with the formatting code that was suggested.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}%
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}  
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{,\thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}}%

\begin{document}
         \tableofcontents

\chapter{Numbers}\label{1-0-0}
\ChapterToc

Some prefatory text
\section{Plain Numbers}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-1-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-1-2}
text text text text text text  

\section{Signed Numbers}\label{1-2-0}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-2-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-2-2}
text text text text text text  


\chapter{Functions}\label{2-0-0}
\ChapterToc

Some text and now some references:

\Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}

\Cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}

\Cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1}

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use.

Comment: @Mico Just realized!!!!

Comment: @schremmer: Load `hyperref` after `titletoc` and `cleveref` even after `hyperref`. It's a well-known fact that `cleveref` should be loaded as last package, in 99.9% of all cases

Comment: The extra texts like `chapter.1` etc. are the remains from the wrong references/addcontentsline writings due to the fact that `cleveref` is loaded too early

Comment: I know and I forget. Sorry about that. The weird things are now gone thanks to your reminding me once again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by Christian you have to load all packages except `cleveref` before `hyperref`. `cleveref` should be loaded after `hyperref`.

If only the chapter tocs should not list the subsections, then you can use the last argument of `\printcontents` to change `tocdepth` locally:

```
\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}

\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{, \thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}\vspace{10mm}}%

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Numbers}\label{1-0-0}
\ChapterToc
Some prefatory text
\section{Plain Numbers}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-1-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-1-2}
text text text text text text  
\section{Signed Numbers}\label{1-2-0}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-2-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-2-2}
text text text text text text  

\chapter{Functions}\label{2-0-0}
\ChapterToc
Some text and now some references:

\Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}

\Cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}

\Cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1}
\end{document}
```

---

If the subsections should be removed from all tocs, then change `tocdepth` globally:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}

\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{, \thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}}%

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Numbers}\label{1-0-0}
\ChapterToc
Some prefatory text
\section{Plain Numbers}\label{1-1-0}
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-1-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-1-2}
text text text text text text  
\section{Signed Numbers}\label{1-2-0}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\subsection{Definition}\label{1-2-1}
text text text text text text  
\subsection{Properties}\label{1-2-2}
text text text text text text  

\chapter{Functions}\label{2-0-0}
\ChapterToc
Some text and now some references:

\Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0}

\Cref{1-1-0} \nameref{1-1-0}

\Cref{1-1-1} \nameref{1-1-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The chapter tocs are now fine. How about the book toc? (You give them a hand and they grab your arm.)

Comment: Change `tocdepth` globally. See my updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! But now I can't figure out how to `indent` the _subsections in the text_ , e.g. **1. Definition** text text text, which I used to do with `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}`  next to which I had written myself a comment, "%Also reformatted with titlesec" which does not help anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `\hspace{10mm}` in `\titleformat{\subsection}...`. Now it is added again.

Comment: I had added it of course but, in fact,  _nothing_ I had been doing in `titleformat{...`, like changing the size of the title, had had _any_ effect. So I wanted to see what _you_ would do. Only now, after you just added the `hspace`, I tried to comment out `titleformat` altogether. Still no change!!!! So, it finally dawned onto me that I must have another `usepackage{titlesec}`and `titleformat` earlier in my (very long and very complex) preamble. And, sure enough ... How dumb can one be when one doe not really know what one is doing! In any case, now ALL is well. Thanks for your GREAT patience.